# There is an error in the code and I do not know how to correct it

Tags: java, android

I have an error in the arrayOfByte1.length and I do not know if it is well structured

```
byte[] arrayOfByte1 = paramAnonymousMessage.getData().getByteArray("DeviceData");
                arrayOfByte1.length;
```

it gives error:
- `Error:(1381, 33) error: not a statement`
- `Error:(1734, 27) error: illegal start of expression`

those two errors in that line of code of arrayOfByte1.length.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Error:(1381, 33) error: not a statement and Error:(1734, 27) error: illegal start of expression, those two errors in that line of code of arrayOfByte1.length.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `arrayOfByte1.length;` is not a statement but a **variable**. So, you need to use variable to hold the value with:

```
int length = arrayOfByte1.length;
```